# Representing $m$ numbers using partial sums of at most $2^m$ numbers

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Let $m$ positive integers $a_1, \cdots, a_m$ be given. Prove that there exist fewer than $2^m$ positive integers $b_1, \cdots,  b_n$ such that all sums of distinct $b_k$s are distinct and all $a_i (i \le m)$ occur among them.

My idea was to be able to represent the $a_i$ in a common way. My first idea was to use bases. That is, let $B=\{b_1,b_2, \cdots, b_n\}=\{1,2^1,\cdots, 2^{n-1}\}$. Then clearly, any partial sum of the elements of $B$ are distinct, and we can represent anything up to $2^n-1$ using the partial sums. But there is no guarantee that $n < 2^m$. Using bases have not yielded useful results.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you idea is correct.  Here is a slight modification to make it work.  We write a number in base-2.  Then any number $x$ corresponds to a set $S(x)$ of the nonzero binary digits (counting from the right).  For example $5 = 101_2$ represents the set $S(101_2) = \{1, 3\}$; the $12 = 1100_2$ represents the set $S(1100_2) = \{3, 4\}$.  Conversely, each set $S$ corresponds to a binary number $N(S)$.  For example, the number corresponding to $\{1, 3, 4\}$ is $1101_2$.

The idea is that we can find a minimal collection of *disjoint* sets, $C = \{B_1, \dots, B_n\}$, such that any number no greater than $\max\{a_m\}$ can be expressed as $N(B_{i_1} \cup \dots \cup B_{i_k})$ for some union of the basic sets, $B_{i_1} \cup \dots \cup B_{i_k}$.

I realize that the proof is kind of hard to read, and I apologize for that.  But hopefully the example in the end can help a little. The modification to your idea is that we can group a few $b_i$ that always share the same value together, and thus reduce the number of $b_i$ needed to satisfy the condition $n < 2^m$.

For example, if we have $a_1 = 111_2$ and $a_2 = 11100_2$, we don't need five numbers $\{1_2, 10_2, 100_2, 1000_2, 10000_2\}$, only three $\{11_2, 100_2, 11000_2\}$ would suffice. Because the first and second (from the right) digits always share the same value in $a_1$ and $a_2$, so are the 4th and 5th digits.

We now show the statement by induction. We start with the case of $m = 1$, then our collection of basic sets has a single member $C^{(1)} = \{ B^{(1)}_1 = S(a_1) \}$.

For $m = 2$, we compute $S(a_2)$.  If $S(a_1) \cap S(a_2) = \emptyset$, then $a_1 = a_2$, nothing is to be done.  Otherwise, we update the collection of basic sets by
$$
\begin{aligned}
C^{(2)}
&= \{
B^{(2)}_1 = B^{(1)}_1 \cap S(a_2), \;
B^{(2)}_2 = B^{(1)}_1 - S(a_2), \;
B^{(2)}_3 = S(a_2) - B^{(1)}_1
\}
\\
&= \{
B^{(2)}_1 = S(a_1) \cap S(a_2), \;
B^{(2)}_2 = S(a_1) - S(a_2), \;
B^{(2)}_3 = S(a_2) - S(a_1)
\}.
\end{aligned}
$$
It is readily seen that the three members of the collection are disjoint, and their unions are distinct.  Further, they can represent $a_1$ by $S(a_1) = B^{(2)}_1 \cup B^{(2)}_2$ and $a_2$ by $S(a_2) = B^{(2)}_1 \cup B^{(2)}_3$.  The desired numbers are $b_i = N(B_i)$ for $i = 1, \dots, n$.  The number of members $n = 3$ in this case, which is less than $2^m = 4$.

Now suppose at the end of the $k$th around (after considering $a_k$),
we have $n < 2^k$ subsets in the collection.
$$
C^{k} = \{
B^{(k)}_1, \dots, B^{(k)}_n \}, 
$$
Consider the action of adding $a_{k+1}$.
For each $B^{(k)}_j$ in the collection, we add two disjoint sets
$B^{(k)}_j \cap S(a_{k+1})$ and $B^{(k)}_j - S(a_{k+1})$
to the new collection $C^{(k+1)}$.
If any of the two is empty, then that set is not added to the collection $C^{(k+1)}$.
Finally, we add a new set (if nonempty) 
$$
S(a_{k+1}) - B^{(k)}_1 - \dots - B^{(k)}_n
$$
to the collection $C^{(k+1)}$.
It is clear that the resulting collection has no greater than $n \times 2 + 1$ sets, and they are mutually disjoint.
Since $n \le 2^k - 1$, we have $2n + 1 \le 2^{k+1} - 1 < 2^{k+1}$ sets in the new collection. This completes our proof.

---

Example.  Consider the $m = 3$ case, and we are given
$$
a_1 = 1111_2, a_2 = 1110011_2, a_3 = 10101010_2.
$$

In the first round, we have in our collection one set,
$C^{(1)} = \{ B^{(1)}_1 = (1,2,3,4) \}$.
The corresponding integer is
$$
b_1 = N( B^{(1)}_1 ) = a_1 = 1111_2.
$$

In the second round, $S(a_2) = (1, 2, 5, 6, 7)$. The collection of basic set are updated as follows.  we split the existing set $B^{(1)}_1 = (1, 2, 3, 4)$ to $B^{(1)}_1 \cap S(a_2) = (1,2)$ and $B^{(1)}_1 - S(a_2) = (3, 4)$, and add a new member of $S(a_2) - B^{(1)}_1 = (5, 6, 7)$.  So the collection has three members
$$
C^{(2)} = \{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{5, 6,7\} \}.
$$
The corresponding binary numbers are
$$
\{ 11_2, 1100_2, 1110000_2 \}.
$$

In the third round, each of the three sets in the collection is further split up by $S(a_3) = \{2, 4, 6, 8\}$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
B^{(2)}_1 \cap S(a_3) &=  \{2\}, \\
B^{(2)}_1 - S(a_3) &=  \{1\}, \\
B^{(2)}_2 \cap S(a_3) &=  \{4\}, \\
B^{(2)}_2 - S(a_3) &=  \{3\}, \\
B^{(2)}_3 \cap S(a_3) &=  \{6\}, \\
B^{(2)}_3 - S(a_3) &=  \{5, 7\}, \\
S(a_3) - B^{(2)}_1 - B^{(2)}_2 - B^{(2)}_3 &= \{8\}.
\end{aligned}
$$
$$
C^{(3)} = \{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}, \{5, 7\}, \{6\}, \{8\}\}.
$$
The corresponding binary numbers are
$$
\{1_2, 10_2, 100_2, 1000_2, 1010000_2, 100000_2, 10000000_2 \}.
$$

Comment: Nicely done. I didn't realize the combinatorial structure of the problem. So I spent a lot of time using unnecessary logs, exponents etc..

Comment: @rah4927. Thank you for the nice question.  I wouldn't be able to solve the problem without your hint of using binary numbers.